# datetime and date in same column

Tags: sas, formatting

I have a question. I have a field in my SAS dataset that has a mixture of datetime and date variables. 
The field is PST_DT and is Type: Numeric. Group: Date. Format: Date9. Length: 8. 
Some values look like this:

```
PST_DT
8/22/2018  11:59:59 PM
8/22/2018
```

How can I turn just the datetime values in date format? I want all the values to be in date format.
Thanks.

Comment: What you have described is not possible.   You cannot store timepart in a DATE variable.  Are you saying you have text file or a character variable that has the strings you posted?

Answer (score 0):

The question does not make much sense as a date variable (number of days since 1960) cannot have a time component at all, much less have it selectively.

If you have a DATETIME value (number of seconds since 1960) and want to convert it to a date value use the `datepart()` function. And attach a date format so that the value displays in a human friendly way.

```
pst_date = datepart(pst_dt);
format pst_date yymmdd10. ;
```

If you have instead a character string then use the `ANYDTDTE.` informat to convert it to a date value.

```
pst_date = input(pst_dt,anydtdte40.);
format pst_date yymmdd10. ;
```